# How to choose Responseformat with Restlet

Tags: java, restlet

I'm new to restlet and i wonder if there is a way to specify the responseformat.

In Odata you can just append $format=json or $format=xml
for example

http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=json

Where or How can i specify my responstyp or format in Restlet?

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can annotate your resources to specify the representation :

```
// Returns a representation in the "text/xml" media type
@Get("xml")
String toString();

// Stores representations in the "text/xml" media type 
// after conversion to a DOM document
@Put("xml")
void store(Document doc)

// Stores representations in the "text/xml" media type after
// conversion to a DOM document and returns a plain text response
@Put("xml:txt")
String store(Document doc)

// Returns a representation in the "text/xml" media type with 
// an inlining depth level of 2
@Get("xml?depth=2")

// Alternative variants
@Put("xml|json:json")

// Alternative variants
@Put("xml+ascii | json+utf8 : json")
```

see also [Resource Package](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/328-restlet.html) documentation